# Cannot select in a select list bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap and jquery. I know it is so simple to create a selection list.
But it is strange that in my page, I cannot select from a select list.

If I remove *class="form-control"*  from the select tag, I can select the option, but the css style is gone.
Could someone tell me what is the issue and how to fix it?

```html
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="ddlSide" class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-3 control-label" >Side</label>
   <div class="col-sm-5">  
        <select class="form-control" id="ddlSide">
             <option value="left">Left</option>
             <option value="right">Right</option>
        </select>                                   
    </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have a printscreen of how the select list looks like for you?

Comment: you drop down is working(run the code snippet) .do you want multiple selection on dropdown?

Comment: I don't seem to understand your problem here. This is fiddle of your code and it works properly: https://jsfiddle.net/qzutqa8q/

Comment: refer this url: https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/